# Modded Minecraft server tech support

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, minecraft

I know we do not allow tech support for modded Minecraft, but does that also include **servers**? I'm primarily talking about the big ones we already have tags for: [minecraft-bukkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bukkit), [minecraft-spigot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-spigot) or bungee (ok, this one is not yet tagged).

The main reason for this question is that one of these popped up in the [reviews](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/272503) and I believe that server questions have a very high probability of being "tech support", be it configs, bugs or errors. Disallowing them would probably end up with most of the questions being off-topic.

If it's about just **Spigot, Bungee, Bukkit**, etc. and not one of their plugins I'd like to vote to **leave them open**, because as long as its about those we can verify pretty well what's going on.

What do you think?

Comment: I feel like making an exception will be more confusing, not only for enforcement, but also in the message we send; "We don't support modded Minecraft tech support, unless you hit one of these exceptions." That's going to be hard to be consistent with, and seem rather arbitrary to those users when we close their questions.

Comment: Good and valid points from you guys. Looks like we keep them off-topic then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Let's keep it off-topic.

Any [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) questions that have something to do with tech support and mods are off-topic. Let's keep it that way.

The questions being on server tech support may make them more important to the OP, but not any better in terms of quality. After all, the reason why Minecraft modded tech support is because the questions often had problems nearly impossible to replicate, without enough context, and no research effort whatsoever.

I think replicating problems on servers is even harder. Not many people have access to the tools used by the OP, and the fact that it's a server, not a singleplayer world adds a lot more factors to what caused the problem.

---

The reason we have the [minecraft-bukkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bukkit) and [minecraft-spigot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-spigot) tags is the same as for the [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods) tag. We **can** answer questions related to mods, like how to use a mod feature, but we **can't** answer tech support questions on modded minecraft, if it's singleplayer or multiplayer.

Tech support questions for modded Minecraft don't belong here, and must be solved in a different way.

Comment: We shouldn't let other forums distract us. There are plenty of forums, wikis and knowledge bases on the internet and the presence of those shouldn't be a reason to not ask those questions on Arqade.

Comment: Except the questions that don't belong here. These posts are not welcome here, which means we have to find another place for them if we want to get any help.

Comment: Of course, but that's not the topic of this meta.

Comment: I'm not trying to promote a Q&A/forum website, I'm just providing information that may be useful advice to someone.

Comment: It's fine. Bukkit forums are a good place (well, not always). But I believe that they're not the only place for those questions.

Comment: For Quijibo and @dly here: where to draw the line? Would you VTC for `Why do hoppers not function properly in Spigot?`? What about `Why is plugin X not compatible with plugin Y?`, `Why is plugin X returning this error when I do this specific thing?` or `How to improve server performance when executing this command from plugin X?` Which of these examples would you allow? I'm for keeping any of these, as long as they are well-researched and can be objectively answered -- e.g. "good question until proven bad" not "bad question until proven good". Your thoughts?

Comment: @RudolfJelin For "Why do hoppers not function properly in Spigot?" and "How to improve server performance when executing this command from plugin X?", I approve. It's more of a matter of an in-game feature than technical issue. The others, though, are just one of those unsolvable questions, and don't belong here.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with server plugins, but if Spigot being installed changes how hoppers work in some way, then "Why do hoppers not function properly in Spigot" is just as valid a question as [this question about a mod that changes the way tools are crafted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238456/tinkers-construct-can-only-be-used-to-make-casts)