# Where can I ask technical troubleshooting questions about modded Minecraft?

Tags: discussion, faq, closing, minecraft

I have an issue with Modded Minecraft. I'm pretty sure it's my computer itself that has the problem. I tried to download and play Skyfactory, and it always gave me an error on startup. Any other modpack also doesn't work and gives the same error.

I've posted my question on Arqade before, but people told me that Arqade isn't the place to ask the question.

Where should I ask this type of question?

Comment: Thanks for the question! We're currently in the process of [writing FAQs](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13490/28182) for other places to go for *all* our off-topic reasons, and the 'Tech support of Modded Minecraft' one was coming soon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will depend entirely on the mod that you're having issues with, but:

## Reach out to the Developer or Community Team surrounding the mod

Minecraft has stabilised a lot over the years, and most of the larger/more popular mods and modpacks have teams of people keeping the mod alive: updating for new versions of Minecraft, adding new features, fixing bugs, and so on. They have their own documentation, bug trackers, FAQs, Community Forums and troubleshooting guides - and in the case that none of those help: a way to contact the team and/or raise a bug.

If you've gone through **ALL the setup/troubleshooting guides** for a particular mod *and are **still** stuck* after that point, then you should look for a way to raise your issue to the team(s) themselves.

Comment: This of course requires you to know which mod causes the issue. The best strategy, requiring the least restarts of Minecraft (which are often very slow with Forge) is to remove half of all mods, check if the issue persists, if yes, remove half of the remaining mods, otherwise put half of the removed mods back in. Further steps require keeping track of which were removed or added before.

Comment: This answer covers specific mods, but what about [general Minecraft mod questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/377395/6297)?

Comment: @l0b0 - Questions about configuring or playing modded Minecraft are fine. You might be interested in [this discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13542/28182), while it's about the wording of the help center, it does summarise most of the OTHER discussions around modded Minecraft's on or off-topicness.